# facebook connect request permission to have users email

Tags: facebook

I have the code below to request the users information for a login to my site but i want to ask the user for permission for their email address also. (i don't want double registrations on my site and want to validate agaist this).

How do i do this?

Also is it possible to ask the user a question related to the registration of my site or will i need check this myself in my code?

```
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars(print_r($e, true)).'</pre>';
    $user = null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get user Email, you have to put permission of

```
email
```

along with your other permissions. then when you request `/me` you will get E-mail in result also. 
[List of various permissions is here.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/)

Comment: sorry if i seem a bit dumb but where do i add the email permission to?

Comment: [Its OK, you can find this using google.](http://www.google.com.pk/search?q=facebook+user+email+permission+php)Specially [this one](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)